# SonarQube can't find unused imports when using Lombok's @Getter and @Setter

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, lombok

When using lombok's generated getters and setters methods the unused imports are not detected.

Example:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class HomeMessage {

    ...
    private String message;
}
```

```java
import java.io.File; // unused import
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping; // unused import

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    HomeRepository homeRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return homeRepository.getReferenceById(1L).getMessage();
    }
}
```

Full working code here: https://github.com/cod-r/spring-boot

Because I'm calling the `.getMessage()` method, which is generated by lombok, the unused imports are not detected by sonarqube.

If I remove the `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations, and create the methods manually then the unused imports will be detected.

I tried to set `sonar.java.libraries` without luck:

```xml
<sonar.java.libraries>${user.home}/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/**/*.jar</sonar.java.libraries>
```

Spring Boot 2.7.3
Lombok 1.18.24
Java 17
SonarQube 9.6-community

Anyone has any solution for this?

Comment: This sounds like something that you should report as a bug to Sonar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in sonarjava and is tracked here: https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/SONARJAVA-4313

The workaround is to add in maven:

```xml
<sonar.java.fileByFile>true</sonar.java.fileByFile>
```

Note that this solution might influence the performance of the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

try config like this in your sonar.properties:`sonar.java.binaries=target/classes`

Comment: I tried this but it has no effect